# TeamCity Extracting Artifact Dependencies

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to create a build step in `Teamcity` that has an `Artifact Dependency` on another build step.

The previous build step's artifacts are available as a `.zip` file.

The build step is able to retrieve the artifacts and they are downloaded to:

```
C:\BuildAgent\work\27f84e3eca3a33d5\artifactdir\artifacts.zip
```

Clearly a `.zip` file isn't much use to me, I need these to be decompressed so that the build step can access the build file.

How do I get TeamCity to decompress the artifacts?

Comment: Too old however just in case someone comes here: Ref: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Artifact+Dependencies

Answer (score 25):

You can use the **Artifact Rules** of Artifact Dependencies to specify the elements of an artifact you would like to use as part of your dependency, **including extracting from an archive**. The Artifact Rule syntax is:

[+:|-:]SourcePath[!ArchivePath][=>DestinationPath]

The **Archive Path** is the element of particular interest for you here.
Using your example, your artifact rule would look something like:

```
artifacts.zip!** => artifactdir
```

This will extract all the contents of the artifacts.zip artifact, and place them in the artifactdir directory at the root of your checkout directory

> ArchivePath is used to extract downloaded compressed artifacts. Zip,
>   7-zip, jar, tar and tar.gz are supported. ArchivePath follows general
>   rules for SourcePath: ant-like wildcards are allowed, the files
>   matched inside the archive will be placed in the directory
>   corresponding to the first wildcard match (relative to destination
>   path)  For example: release.zip!*.dll command will extract all .dll
>   files residing in the root of the release.zip artifact.

You can find the full TeamCity Artifact Dependency documentation [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Artifact+Dependencies)

Comment: JFYI: If the archive contains symlinks, after extraction on TeamCity they will be broken.